# Evaluating the sum $\sum_{k = 0}^n (-1)^{n - k}\binom{n}{k}k$

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics

Let $$a_n=\sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^{n-k}{n \choose k}k$$

I was asked to show that $a_1=1$ and that $\forall n \neq 1, a_n=0$.

Showing that $a_1 = 1$ is quite easy, I can manage to show that $a_0 = 0$ but how can I show this for $n>1$ ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have $$\left(e^{x}-1\right)^{n}=\sum_{k\leq n}\dbinom{n}{k}\left(-1\right)^{n-k}e^{kx}$$
 then $$\frac{d}{dx}\left(e^{x}-1\right)^{n}=\sum_{k\leq n}\dbinom{n}{k}\left(-1\right)^{n-k}ke^{kx}$$
 hence$$\left.\frac{d}{dx}\left(e^{x}-1\right)^{n}\right|_{x=0}=\sum_{k\leq n}\dbinom{n}{k}\left(-1\right)^{n-k}k.$$

Comment: Thank you ! (I used $(x-1)^n$ instead but that tip does the thing)

Answer (score 1):

$$a_n = \sum_{k=0}^n {n\choose k}(-1)^{n-k} = \sum_{k=0}^n {n\choose k}(1)^k(-1)^{n-k} = (1 - 1)^n = 0^n = 0$$

(Using the binomial theorem)

Comment: Indeed, I actually forgot a $k$. Can I still apply binomial theorem ?